# Heroku move files after deploy

Tags: heroku

I use the Apt buildpack to install tesseract.
Now I need to copy a config file into a directory
that only exists after the tesseract installation.

Where can I put something like "mv configfile destination"
that gets executed after the tesseract installation?

This should happen automatically during a deploy and
not manually after the fact.

Thanks
Andre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the NPM `postinstall` hook to perform build tasks, load dev dependencies for those tasks, cleanup, etc.

From the scripts section of your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": { 
  "postinstall": "node ./ops/heroku-build.js" 
}
```

In that file you can use `fs` to copy the file, and do any other tasks that need to be accomplished.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process